# Duplicating collections in 2.81 not copying everything

Tags: groups, collections

I'm trying to copy everything in a collection (*I don't want them linked*) 
 called **Camera.001** from one scene to another scene *(the second scene is in the same blender file)*.  But I notice that when I duplicate a collection called **Camera.001** not everything is duplicated over to the **Camera.002** collection. See animated gif below.

The parented text **to_see_it_animated_ijk4de_website** is not copied over to the **Camera.002** collection is this a bug, am I doing something wrong, is there a workaround.

I'm using Blender 2.81 on Ubuntu 18.04 64bit

[image: Collection issue]

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure, you're looking into the right collection? In the gif, the newly created collection has the .002 appendix, but you're looking into the .001.

Comment: @JACHYM MICHAL  :-) yes take a look at the arrows the one on the right are down arrows.  I made the animated gif very large just so it would show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *parented text object* is actually missing even from the .001 collection (it's *grayed out*).
So it won't get duplicated.

**How it happens**
When you move *parented (child) object* into another collection, the parent relationship gets broken.
The child object icon will be *grayed out*, so you know it's broken.

And broken relationship doesn't get duplicated.

**Solution**
Find your *parented text object*, and move it back into the .001 Collection.
Then it will reconnect and will be duplicated with the parent.

*Moving a parented object into a different collection breaks the relationship.

Moving it back reconnects it.*

[image]

Comment: That fixed the issue with the parent child relationship thanks, but it still doesn't seem to allow me to copy a collection from one scene to another scene.

Comment: Well, moving collections between scenes is done a bit differently. Would you mind asking that as another question?

Comment: sure I added it https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163330/duplicating-copy-collections-unlinked-in-2-81-from-one-scene-to-another-scen