# Duplicating / copy collections (unlinked) in 2.81 from one scene to another scene

Tags: collections

I'm trying to copy everything in a collection (I don't want them linked) called Camera.001 from one scene to another scene (the second scene is in the same blender file). But I notice that when I duplicate a collection called Camera.001 that when I paste it into another scene nothing shows up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move Collections between Scenes using outliner.

1. Set the *Display Mode* to *Scenes*
2. Grab the Collection and drag it to another Scene

*Example:

Moving Collection 01 from Scene 01 to Scene 02.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks..... :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)